# Using jquery.Gantt and return wrong date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, utc

i'm using [jquery gantt](http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/) and my date is wrong. Example: i signed up in day 18, and my result ever is 1 day more. Registry day 19, and my result is 20. What i make? I dont know :/

My code:

```
<script>

$(function() {

    "use strict";

    var today = moment();
    var andTwoHours = moment().add("hours",2);
    var today_friendly = "/Date(" + today.valueOf() + ")/";
    var next_friendly = "/Date(" + andTwoHours.valueOf() + ")/";
    var today_friendly = today.toDate();
    var next_friendly = andTwoHours.toDate();
    var maxDate = moment().add("days",10).toDate();

    $('.gantt').gantt({
         source: [{
              name: '<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:descricao] %>',
              desc: '<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:status] %>'+"% concluído",
              values: [{
                   from: "/Date(<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:data_inicial] %>)/",
                   to: "/Date(<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:data_final] %>)/",
                   //from:today_friendly,
                   //to:next_friendly,
                   label:"<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:descricao] %>", 
                   customClass: "ganttRed"
             }]
         }],    
         maxScale:"months",
         navigate: "scroll",
         waitText: "Aguarde...",
         dow: ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"],
         months: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"]
    });

});

</script>
```

Anything I explain better, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I just convert to_time and to_i in my controller and finish! :)